# $ flow README.md

Tags: git, command, git-bash

I am trying to create a file from git bash.

```
WeirdGhost@Deepmind MINGW64 ~/project1/demo (master)
$ git status
On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)

WeirdGhost@Deepmind MINGW64 ~/project1/demo (master)
$ mate README.md
bash: mate: command not found
```

Comment: Looks like the `mate` command cannot be found: `mate: command not found`. Whatever `mate` is, did you install it and add it to your PATH as an environment variable?

Comment: Do i need to add it to the environment variable?